# Select rows that contain both English and non-English characters

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

Ok so I have a column in a table in SQL Server.
Each records have a string (i.e. names)
SOME of the strings have English AND NON ENGLISH characters.

I have to select ONLY the records that have English AND NON English characters.

How do I go about doing that?

My try...

```
Select * from Table
Where Nameofthecolumn NOT LIKE '%[A-Z]%'
Go
```

This will give me EMPTY table.

I know for sure that there are at least two records that have english and non-english characters.

I need those two records as output.

I was trying to do

```
Select * from Table
Where Nameofthecolumn NOT LIKE '%[A-Z,a-z]%' AND Like '%[A-Z,a-z]%'
Go
```

but turns out you can use boolean with Like/Not Like.

Please guide me the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How about reversing your search, e.g. find anything that doesn't match A-Z:

```
... WHERE col LIKE '%[^A-Z]%' AND col LIKE '%[A-Z]%';
```

If the collation is case insensitive you shouldn't need a-z, if it is case sensitive you could add the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391%28v=sql.100%29.aspx) clause. But you may want to filter out spaces, numbers and other non-alphanumerics that are expected.

Comment: @JohnSmith everyone is guessing. Can you please provide some sample data, showing both rows you want to include and rows you want to exclude?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
select 1 as field1,'1' as field2 into #data
union all select 1,'abc'
union all select 2,'abc'
union all select 3,'999'


SELECT * FROM 
(
select field1,field2
,MAX(CASE WHEN field2 NOT LIKE '%[A-Z,a-z]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) 
 + MAX(CASE WHEN field2 LIKE '%[A-Z,a-z]%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) OVER (PARTITION BY field1) as chars 
FROM #data
) alias
WHERE chars =2
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but we haven't learned union, then, else, etc so there should be another way. If nothing works, I can try that.

Comment: As Aaron said, can you provide some sample data and what queries would be acceptable - also I presume then that this is homework?